# Крашится Code::Blocks при наборе "voi", "dou"

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

Суть: при наборе "voi(d)" "dou(ble)" в КодБлоксах 16.01 (mingw) крашится на i/u соответственно. При этом, насколько я понял, никакого лога/репорта нет. Судя по всему, как-то связано с автокомплитом. Кто стакивался с таким и как это лечится?

UPD: снёс полностью конфигурацию C::B - проблема исчезла. Но не каждый же раз сбрасывать конфигурацию.

Comment: Возможно, но там, кажись, уже есть такой баг.

Comment: А на других типах не крэшится? Тогда можно поиграть в квест: напиши программу без void и double.